# How to implement modal swipe to down like instagram?

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

I'm currently working on an React Native project. I need to implement a feature similar to "Swipe Down To close Modal" on Instagram

Comment: https://github.com/nysamnang/react-native-raw-bottom-sheet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you're using [@react-native-community/react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) package. In the library documents, you can see that there is a property called **swipeDirection** which is either a string or an array that can be one or many of the following options; 'up', 'down', 'left' or 'right.

You can also set the threshold required swipe action to be completed by using **swipeThreshold** property. The default is 100 according to the library documents.

Here's an example of the modal;

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native;
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

const ModalComponent = props => {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

    return (
        <Modal isVisible={isVisible}
               swipeDirection="down"
               //swipeDirection={["up", "down", "left", "right"]}
               onSwipeComplete={(e) => { setIsVisible(false); })
               style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end', margin: 0, }} >
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'steelblue' }}>
                <Text>Hello Modal</Text>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    );
};

export {ModalComponent};
```